# Get currency rate by currency code magento 2

Tags: currency, magento2

I need to currency rate by currency code in magento 2.

```
$currency =  $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface');
$currencySymbol = $currency->getRate('USD');
```

I tried above code it returns fatal error.

Answer (score 2):

you could try with :

```
$storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getRate('USD');
```

Store manager is here :

```
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Direct Injection to accomplish this instead of the Object Manager. Here is the code using Tim Zwinkels suggestion in an order placed observer class:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class SalesOrderSaveAfterObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    private $_logger;

    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        StoreManagerInterface $_storeManager
    ){
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_storeManager = $_storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param EventObserver $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $currencyCode = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
        $grandTotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
        $currencyRate = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($currencyCode);
        $this->_logger->log('INFO', 'Currency Code: ' . $currencyCode);
        $this->_logger->log('INFO', 'Grand Total: ' . $grandTotal);
        $this->_logger->log('INFO', 'Currency Rate: ' . $currencyRate);
    }
}
```

This will log all the Currency Code, Grand Total and Currency Rate in the var/log/system.log file.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code to avail the currency rate by using currency code:

```
$currency = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory')->create()->load($currencyCode);
 $currencySymbol = $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
```